# Is there a documentation for pdfs

Tags: file, pdf, byte

I am wondering if there is a documentation for PDF like for bitmap (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Bitmap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally pdf was a format under Adobe control. They published pdf references for the different revisions of the format.

In 2008, though, they gave the control over the format to ISO who publishes the PDF specification version now.

- *ISO 32000-1:2008* in 2008, mostly a copy of the Adobe PDF 1.7 reference - Adobe was allowed to publish a freely downloadable copy thereof (with merely the ISO headers removed) on their site, you can currently download it at http://www.adobe.com/go/pdfreference/ (yes, this points to the file you have meanwhile found yourself).
- *ISO 32000-2:2017* in 2017, here PDF version 2.0 is specified including a number of new features but also numerous corrections and clarifications of details discussed in ISO 32000-1 - there is no official free download of this standard, you have to buy a copy from ISO or your local standardization body.
- *ISO 32000-2:2020* in 2020, clarifications of PDF 2.0, several chapters of the spec re-written, and again no official free download.

Currently further clarification questions are asked and answered at https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf-issues with the resulting PDF 2.0 corrections collected [here](https://pdf-issues.pdfa.org/32000-2-2020/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
This is what I was searching for.
https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf